# wordpress override template hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have a custom post type "accommodation" and a custom taxonomy "tax_destination".
When i put this url:

```
/?post_type=accommodation&tax_destination=granada
```

the template rendered is: taxonomy-tax_destination.php

Is it possible to use archive-accommodation.php instead?

What I want is to show the accommodation's list for that taxonomy using the archive template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has a handy filter called [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) that allows you to override which template files are included on a particular request. You can combine that with a check using [`is_tax()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax). The `$term` argument is optional, but since you included one I'm going to include it so it only works for the `granada` term:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'accommodation_template', 99 );
function accommodation_template( $template ) {
    if( is_tax( 'tax_destination', 'granada' ) ){
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'archive-accommodation.php' ) );
        if( !empty( $new_template ) ){
            return $new_template;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

If you put this in your `functions.php` file, it will determine if the current request is for the term `granada` in the taxonomy `tax_destination`, and return the `archive-accommodation.php` template.

Note: If you reuse those tax/terms on other post types, you may need to include `is_post_type_archive( 'accommodation' )` or `get_post_type() == 'accommodation'` to your if statement as well.

Comment: It works perfectly, but I've replaced the is_tax by is_post_type_archive( 'accommodation' ) ."Granada" is a term and I have a lot of terms for that taxonomy.

Comment: Well, with WPML it works for default language but when i change to another language the template uses again the taxonomy-tax_destination.php

Comment: Do you have a translation set for `accommodation`? You may need `is_post_type_archive( __( 'accommodation' ) )`, though I haven't seen it affect registered labels like that

Comment: No, it's not translated. anyway i've tryed __('accommodation') with no luck.
Some debug info: template: "taxonomy-tax_destination.php" taxonomy: "tax_destination" term: "granada" get_query_var(post_type): "accommodation"
(get_post_type()): accommodation

Comment: And it also happen with all my custom post types, no way to show the archive for other languages than default one

Comment: Fixed changing the priority: add_filter( 'template_include', 'accommodation_template', PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );